# join 2 tables with ForeignKey in django

Tags: django, database, django-models, foreign-keys, django-database

i have an image table which is made of all of my images
and i have a product table
i want to use more than one image in my product table
how is this possible ?
i dont want to write ForeignKey in image table because i want to use my images somewhere else

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Image (models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Product (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you want to have a **Many to Many** relationship between `Image` and `Product`, then you can simply add this to the `Product` class

```py
from django.db import models

class Image (models.Model):
    ...

class Product (models.Model):
    ...
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image)
```